# Extract number of days from an sql query using pandas, and write the result in a new column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column (called "sql") is an sql query string (that have at least two dates inside it). I need to compute the number of days between the two dates, and store it in a new column of the df.

Example "sql" column `df['sql'].iloc[0]` of my dataframe:

```
'WITH table1 AS (\n SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN \'2023-01-01\' AND \'2023-01-04\' ...'
```

I can extract the dates from the first line of the sql query using:

```
sqlquery = df.sql.iloc[0]
ldates = re.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', sqlquery)
```

And I can compute the number of days using something like

```
num_days = (pd.to_datetime(ldates[1])-pd.to_datetime(ldates[0])).days
```

However, this only concerns the first line of the df (hence the `.iloc[0]`). My problem is that I don't know how to process this information for all lines, and write the result into a new column of the df. I tried something like:

```
df['num_days'] = (
                     pd.to_datetime(re.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', df.sql)[1]
                     ) -
                     pd.to_datetime(re.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', df.sql)[0]
                     )
                 ).days
```

But the re.findall from the "df.sql" part throws an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any ideas on how can I achieve that? Maybe using a for loop to every row of the df?

Comment: your date columns contain another data, because appears error, check columns all value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `df.sql` as the second argument of `re.findall()`, you're passing a whole pandas series of strings (i.e. the whole `sql` column of your data frame), but `findall` is expecting just one string (or byte-like object).

You want to use pandas `apply` on the `sql` field. This applies a function (usually a lambda function) to each entry in the column. E.g. If you have a data frame with numeric values in column `a`, then `df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda n: n+2)` will create a new column `b` with entries that are 2 more than the value in `a`. It applies the function `lambda n: n+2` to column `a`, one entry at a time.

In your case, the following code will apply the function `date_comp` to the `sql` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'n': [1, 2],
'sql': ['WITH table1 AS (\n SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN \'2023-01-01\' AND \'2023-01-04\' ...',
        'WITH table1 AS (\n SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN \'2023-02-04\' AND \'2023-03-06\' ...'] 
})

def date_comp(s: str):
    # date_comp function takes a string as argument
    # finds all dates of that format in the string
    dates_list = re.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', s)
    # converts these strings to datetime
    dates_list = [pd.to_datetime(_d) for _d in dates_list]
    if len(dates_list) < 2:
        # if the string doesn't contain at least 2 dates, return None, or 0, or raise error
        return 0
    return (dates_list[1] - dates_list[0]).days

df['days'] = df['sql'].apply(date_comp)
```

The resulting dataframe `df` looks like

| n | sql | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WITH table1 AS ... | 3 |
| 2 | WITH table1 AS ... | 30 |